# C# application works much slower using compiled IronPython standard library

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

When I load modules from standard library as source .py files in this application, elapsed time after end equals approximately 4 seconds:

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"C:\Users\Montgomery1944\Documents\Libs\IronPython-2.7.1\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
@"from distutils import dir_util
import ftplib
import os
import tempfile
import zipfile");
source.Execute(scope);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.Seconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But when I load modules from standard library compiled using script:

```
import System
import pyc
def get_files(dir):
    res = [file for file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, '*.py')]
    dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
    if dirs:
        for dir in dirs:
            res += get_files(dir)
    return res
files = get_files(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\Lib')
pyc.Main(files + ['/out:IronPython.Stdlib'])
```

in this application, elapsed time after end equals approximately 20 seconds:

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
@"import clr
clr.AddReference('IronPython.Stdlib')
from distutils import dir_util
import ftplib
import os
import tempfile
import zipfile");
source.Execute(scope);
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.Seconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Why loading modules from precompiled library is much slower than loading from source files?

Comment: You cannot compare the two. Only in the second case you import clr with the AddReference.

Comment: Yes, i can compare it, in first application I include standard library by using "paths.Add(@"C:\Users\Montgomery1944\Documents\Libs\IronPython-2.7.1\Lib")", in second by "clr.AddReference('IronPython.Stdlib')", it is the same standard library, but in diffrent form. And as for me loading of compiled version should be faster, but it is not.

Comment: Yes, but you don't use clr yet in the first case. I think there's the catch.

Comment: I think it is more a case of the compiled library containing EVERYTHING in the standard library  if you just run @"import clr
clr.AddReference('IronPython.Stdlib'))  how long does it take?