# IronPython StdLib from NuGet cannot be found

Tags: python, visual-studio, nuget, ironpython

I have installed IronPython and IronPython.StdLib from NuGet. From other posts on the topic (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017257/c-sharp-application-works-much-slower-using-compiled-ironpython-standard-library)), it seems like I can simply add

```
clr.AddReference(IronPython.StdLib)
```

to my python module and can then use CPython modules such as 'os'. But it doesn't work.

With the above line, I get the following error:

```
"Could not add reference to assembly IronPython.StdLib"
```

If I comment the line, 'os' cannot be found:

```
"No module named os"
```

How do I get my python script to find the NuGet-installed StdLib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IronPyton.StdLib package does not have a pre-compiled stdlib (although that's something I've considered); it has the actual stdlib files themselves, which should get unpacked into a `Lib` directory in your project. You need to add that directory to the IronPython search path using `engine.SetSearchPaths` and you should be able to import.

Comment: Is it possible to embed these into the .exe? I would very much like to be able to distribute a single .exe without installer.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. All of the pieces are place (importing from .exe resources, mainly) but the pyc.py tool has not been updated to support it. We've had a lot of requests for single-exe support but no one has had the time to implement it. :(